# Get another table's rows when rows matches with a specific table column value and append to new table in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table called Table A where I want to get the Table B's rows whenever the id appears in Table A and append the rows to a new table.

Table A

| id | week |
| --- | --- |
| f8y | 50 |
| ab5 | 50 |

Table B

| id | week |
| --- | --- |
| f8y | 40 |
| f8y | 35 |
| 2op | 23 |

Desired output

| id | week |
| --- | --- |
| f8y | 35 |
| f8y | 40 |
| f8y | 50 |

Answer (score 1):

Do you wan to `concat` the common ids?

```
common = set(dfA['id']).intersection(dfB['id'])
# {'f8y'}

out = pd.concat([dfA[dfA['id'].isin(common)], dfB[dfB['id'].isin(common)]])
```

output:

```
    id  week
0  f8y    50
0  f8y    40
1  f8y    35
```